# How to remove .x and .y in merge in r

Tags: r, merge

I use this function to merge two data frame as follows:

```html
merge(df1,df2,by="id")
```

Some columns have the same names, because of this, I will get .x and .y for the common columns. I want just to remove .x and .y. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Just select only the columns needed i.e. `merge(df1, df2[nm1], by = 'id')` where `nm1 <- c('id', 'othercol')`

Comment: I have 64 columns with .x and .y  I want to remove all .x and .y

Comment: `.x` and `.y` results only because there are same column names in both data.  I would subset the second dataset with only the 'id' and the potential column you wanted in the merged

Comment: We cant remove them using str_remove or str_extract or using a loop?

Comment: Yes, you can with `rename_at/str_remove`

Comment: I use df %>% mutate( A.B = str_remove(A.B, .*)), bu I dont get it

Comment: I meant `merge(df1,df2,by="id") %>% rename_at(vars(matches('\\.[xy]")), ~ str_remove(., "\\..*$"))`. But this may create duplicte column names

Comment: looks an error in your code?

Comment: I meant that if you are removing the `.x` and `.y`, this results in column names that are duplicate and the data.frame doesn't allow

Comment: If the duplicate column names also have the same values then you can add them to the by= and you will only  get one instance with no .x or .y .

Comment: the duplicate column names do not have the same value, let's say class in df1 and class in df2, they have different values.

Comment: If they have different value and you remove the .x and .y then they will have the same name and it will be impossible to refer to the second one by name.  If DF is the result then DF$class will always refer to the first one.  The only way to refer to the second one will be to find its column number and refer to it that way.